# Azure DevOps pipeline - custom name of output file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I would like to ask you if it possible to create a custom name of zip file using output argument in in yaml task : **DotNetCoreCLI@2**

**My yaml code:**

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    projects: '**/XXXProject.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/newzipname'
    zipAfterPublish: true
```

**Current output:**

> ../newzipname/XXXProject.zip

**What I would like to achieve:**

> ../newzipname.zip

*Thanks in advance for all answers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported in [DotNetCoreCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task.

Another option is to add [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) task and rename the .zip file produced by DotNetCoreCLI task. You can use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1) PowerShell command for that.